# How i can change number that displaying on QPushButton?

Tags: c++, qt, qstring, qpushbutton

I have a QPushButton, this button has a text on it, this text is a number. In a slot of another object i want to change number that displayed on button, but when i call

```
MyButton->setText(QString("%1").arg(Number));
```

or

```
QString tmp;
tmp.setNum(Number);
MyButton->setText(tmp);
```

text on button dosen't changes.
But when i call

```
MyButton->setText("some random text");
```

it works fine.
How i can change number that displaying on button?

Part of my code:

```
sortWindow::sortWindow(QWidget *parrent)
{
...
MyButton = new QPushButton;
QString tmp(QString("%1").arg(Number));
MyButton.setText(tmp);
...
}
```

and

```
void sortWindow::workOnSignal(int index)
{
...
if (something)
{
...
QString tmp;
tmp.setNum(Number);
MyButton->setText(tmp);
...
}
```

Comment: What is the type of "Number" ? There's a ")" missing at the end of the first line but I think that's just a copy/paste error.

Comment: Check the value of `tmp`, either in the debugger or by printing it with qDebug().

Comment: Number is int, and yes it was just copy/pste error at the end of first line.
tmp has correct value via checking through qDebug()

Comment: this is not C++ question

Comment: To Hesam Qodsi
This is the same as I created MyButton, but I need to change it.

Comment: Maybe you should show us a little bit more of your code, I can't see anything wrong with that.

Comment: Just use `MyButton->setText(QString::number(index));`.

Comment: Frerich Raabe thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Type of `Number` must be `int`. So it will work properly.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QPushButton>

int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc,argv);

    QPushButton *pd = new QPushButton;
    pd->setText(QString("%1").arg(1234));
    pd->show();

    return app.exec();
}
```